# Skip first row in a file

Tags: python, row

I'm trying to open 2 files, read the contents of both files, and export the rows of both files to an output file.

The issue I'm having is that the 2nd file that I'm reading in has the same headers in it's first row as the 1st, so I'm trying to skip writing the 1st row of the 2nd file to my new `outputFile`, but the code written below doesn't execute that.

I know my code says `if row[1]=='Full Name'` and not `column[1]`, but if I skip writting `row[1]` to the `outputFile`, it skips the first column and not the first row, so I figured I'd use that first column in my `if` statement. The first column's header in my input data is `Full Name`, so that's why I used that particular if statement.

I didn't include incoming data because I didn't think it was necesary to answer this question, but if you feel it would be helpful, I'm more than glad to post it up here.

If anyone can help me skip writing the first row of the second incoming into my `outputFile` it would be greatly appreciated.

```
import csv, sys

firstFile = open(sys.argv[1],'rU')# U to parse
reader1 = csv.reader(firstFile, delimiter=',')
outputFile = open((sys.argv[3]), 'w')
for row in reader1:
     row=(str(row))
     row=row.replace("'", "")
     row=row.replace("[", "")
     row=row.replace("]", "")
     outputFile.write(row)
     outputFile.write('\n')

 secondFile = open(sys.argv[2],'rU')
 reader2 = csv.reader(secondFile, delimiter=',')
 for row in reader2:
     row=(str(row))
     row=row.replace("'", "")
     row=row.replace("[", "")
     row=row.replace("]", "")
     if row[1]=='Full Name':
         next(reader2)
    else:
         outputFile.write(row)
         outputFile.write('\n')
```

Comment: Have a counter that resets to 0 on opening each file. From there increment by 1 for each row. Using this you can get it to ignore the first row...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `next` function:

```
secondFile = open(sys.argv[2],'rU')

# skip first line
next(secondFile)

# csv parser does not see the first line of the file
reader2 = csv.reader(secondFile, delimiter=',')
```

Comment: almost, check the 4th line ;)